# VBA copy row range to another workbook with VBScript

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I'm trying to copy a few segments of a single row in one workbook to another workbook, here is my script, not sure but I'm getting a (Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set).

```
Sub copyToXml()
Set xlBook1 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\roperalta\Desktop\Book1.xlsx", 0, True)
Set xlBook2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\roperalta\Desktop\PBJ_Excel_to_XML_Template_v_2_00_3.xlsx", 0, True)

xlBook2.Sheets("Header").Range("B3:D3").Value = xlBook1.Sheets("Sheet0 (2)").Range("B2:D2")

xlBook1.Close
End Sub
```

The error is coming from line 5.

```
xlBook2.Sheets("Header").Range("B3:D3").Value = xlBook1.Sheets("Sheet0 (2)").Range("B2:D2")
```

Here is the script:

```
Dim xlBook, xlApp 

Set xlApp = createObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\roperalta\Desktop\PBJ_Excel_to_XML_Template_v_2_00_3.xlsx", 0, False)
Set xlmodule = xlBook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)
strCode = _
"Sub copyToXml()" & vbCr & _
"    Set xlBook1 = Workbooks.Open(""C:\Users\roperalta\Desktop\Book1.xlsx"", 0, False)" & vbCr & _
"    Set xlBook2 = Workbooks.Open(""C:\Users\roperalta\Desktop\PBJ_Excel_to_XML_Template_v_2_00_3.xlsx"", 0, False)" & vbCr & _
"" & vbCr & _
"    xlBook2.Sheets(""Header"").Range(""B3:D3"").Value = xlBook1.Sheets(""Sheet0 (2)"").Range(""B2:D2"").Value" & vbCr & _
"" & vbCr & _
"    xlBook1.Close" & vbCr & _
"End Sub"
xlmodule.CodeModule.AddFromString strCode

xlBook.Save
xlApp.Run "Module1.copyToXml"
Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlBook = Nothing
```

Edited script:

```
"    Set xlBook2 = Workbooks(""C:\Users\roperalta\Desktop\PBJ_Excel_to_XML_Template_v_2_00_3.xlsx"")" & vbCr & _
```

Comment: Try adding `.Value` after the second one

Comment: still getting the same error.

Comment: It shouldn't be causing this specific error, but why are you copying info to a file that is opened as read-only?

Comment: I don't really know actually so i took it out.

Comment: Are either of `"C:\Users\roperalta\Desktop\Book1.xlsx"` and `"C:\Users\roperalta\Desktop\PBJ_Excel_to_XML_Template_v_2_00_3.xlsx"` already open when you start the macro?

Comment: Yes they are open when starting macro with in the PBJ sheet. But when i run from a .vbs file they open first than the macro runs

Comment: VBS?!??!?!  How is VBScript involved?  That changes things dramatically.  If this is VBScript, we need to see how you are creating the `Workbooks` collection.

Comment: I'm  using a batch file to call the vbscript to automate this process without have to run the macro manually.

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your VBScript code where you are (a) defining any global-scoped variables, (b) creating the Excel Application object (c) calling the `copyToXml` procedure.  (Your current `copyToXml` code is using a `Workbooks` object that I'm betting you haven't created anywhere.)

Comment: And please update the tags to say that this is [vbscript] so that people who use VBScript might be able to help.

Comment: My gut feeling is that reopening the `"C:\Users\roperalta\Desktop\PBJ_Excel_to_XML_Template_v_2_00_3.xlsx"` workbook without the macros is going to mean that it can't continue the macro that it was running from that workbook.  But I am about to test.

Comment: I get an "Error: Unknown runtime error" "Code: 800A9C68" once it reopens the workbook and has lost the macros.

Comment: When i take out the 2nd open workbook, i get an error subscript out of range.

Comment: (a) Is there a reason why you are trying to put macros in a non-macro-enabled workbook? (b) Is there a reason why you don't just put the `copyToXml` functionality into the VBScript code itself?

Comment: Yeah, I am very new to this, It's like my 3rd day working with vba in excel. But i have to clock out. so maybe if you guys are still willing to help, I'll be back tomorrow. Thanks a lot you guys, I really appreciate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this VBS:

---

```
    Const FILE1 = "C:\Users\roperalta\Desktop\Book1.xlsx"
    Const FILE2 = "C:\Users\roperalta\Desktop\PBJ_Excel_to_XML_Template_v_2_00_3.xlsx"

    Dim xlApp 
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    Dim wb1, wb2
    With xlApp
        .Visible = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        Set wb1 = .Workbooks.Open(FILE1, 0, False)
        Set wb2 = .Workbooks.Open(FILE2, 0, False)
    End With

    Dim ws1, ws2
    Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("Sheet0 (2)")
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("Header")

        ws2.Range("B3:D3").Value2 = ws1.Range("B2:D2").Value2

    wb2.Save
    wb1.Close
    'wb2.Close
    'xlApp.Quit

    Set ws1 = Nothing
    Set ws2 = Nothing
    Set wb1 = Nothing
    'Set wb2 = Nothing
    'Set xlApp = Nothing
```

Comment: #3 should give a "subscript out of range error" (But anything is possible I guess)

Comment: I know - with the same scenario I can't get `Run-time error '91`... (file not found is 1004) @YowE3K

Comment: I've changed the true values to false and added the .Value also checked the sheet names and they are correct, but I'm still getting the same error. When I look up the error it says that some object is not being set, I'm guessing the workbook object, or the worksheet object, but I'm not sure what could be the real issue here.

Comment: Try adding these 2 lines: 1. `xlBook2.Sheets("Header").Activate` and 2. `xlBook1.Sheets("Sheet0 (2)").Activate` after the 2nd `Set` statement - which one is showing the error?

Comment: @paulbica Warning: OP has just mentioned ".vbs file" in a comment, so I suspect that the whole question has just changed.

Comment: should i post my vbscript

Comment: Yes - we need to see the creation of the Excel app, and you'll probably need to qualify the `Workbooks` objects

Comment: Yeas!! This answer is how I think it **should** be done.  None of this sticking macros into a workbook so that we can invoke the macro mucking about.

Comment: yes, the OP looks like a convoluted way to do something simple @YowE3K

Comment: Thanks @YowE3K and paul bica This script works great!!! I'm going to rewrite a bunch of other scripts that I did with this format style, without all the convolusion LOL.